# A question from boundedness property of LMT

Tags: pde

I have the following PDE
$$
u_t = k \Delta u + \alpha u H(u-c) 
$$
I am trying to show the boundedness property to apply LMT. I get confused with the estimates of third term.

The space I have
$$V = \{v\in H^1(\Omega) : v(0,y)=v(1,y)~ and~ \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}(x,0)=0=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}(x,1)\}$$
and the function $H$ is a linear function and it is $0 \leq H(x) \leq 1$.

The third term in the bilinear form is

$$
|(\alpha u^{n+1} H(u^n-q_c),w)_{L^2(\Omega)}| \leq \alpha \|u^{n+1}\|_{L^2(\Omega)} \|w\|_{L^2(\Omega)} \leq \alpha \|u^{n+1}\|_{H^1(\Omega)} \|w\|_{H^1(\Omega)} 
$$

Is third estimate correct here? Can I split the $L^2$ norm of $u^{n+1}H(u^n-q_c)$ integrands?

Comment: How can $H$ be linear and $0\leq H(x)\leq 1$?

Comment: By "LMT" do you mean the Lax-Milgram theorem?